# PostgreSQL: LIMIT + ORDER returning inconsistent results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Whenever I run a query which contains both the `LIMIT` and the `ORDER BY` keywords, I get inconsistent results depending on the number of items specified in the `LIMIT` clause:

For example, the following query:

```
SELECT "people"."name" 
FROM "people" 
WHERE "people"."type" = 2 
ORDER BY score desc, number desc 
LIMIT 50
```

gives me this as a result:

```
[John, Jack, Amy, Brad, Tom, ...]
```

(John and Jack both have the same values for their `score` and `number` attributes. So do Amy, Brad, and Tom, in fact.)

Now, when I run:

```
SELECT "people"."name" 
FROM "people" 
WHERE "people"."type" = 2 
ORDER BY score desc, number desc 
LIMIT 5
```

I get the following result:

```
[Jack, John, Tom, Amy, Brad]
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this with MySQL if you are asking a question about Postgres?

Answer (score 5):

When the order by value is the same, the database can decide what the next sort is, and it's possible it may change over many runs of the same query.

Try adding a secondary order by

```
ORDER BY score, name
```

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. But your solution does not solve the problem. I need it to be sorted by score desc, and name desc. Do you happen to know anyway to force it to do a consistent order

Comment: @user2158382: you *have* to specify a combination of columns that is basically unique at some place. You could include e.g. the primary key as the last sort column in order to "resolve" the sorting for duplicates.

Comment: ah I see perfect. That sounds like a good idea, I dont know why I didnt think of that.